# Raspberry Pi Camera Module, Time Lapse Photography

Tags: raspbian, camera

I have created a Raspberry Pi time lapse photography by following the steps in this website:

http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-time-lapse-photography-with-a-raspberry-pi--cms-20794

What I'm trying to do now is how can I send the pics taken to a website or to a place where I can retrieve the photos on my computer

Any ideas?

Comment: If you google grieve.py you'll find a script which backs up /syncs your entire pi to a google drive account with instructions to add to the corn table. If you YouTube pimothion, you'll also find a really great video.

Answer (score 2):

You could use samba on your raspberry to make the folder where your photos are saved  a samba share (windows filesharing) and connect this share to your computer as an own drive letter. So you can access the filesystem of your raspberry from your computer very easily. 
-->  http://raspberrywebserver.com/serveradmin/share-your-raspberry-pis-files-and-folders-across-a-network.html

Or you can mount your raspberrys filesystem to your desktop box by using the ssh filesystem.
--> http://www.howtoforge.com/mounting-remote-directories-with-sshfs-on-debian-squeeze

Answer (score 2):

I am using a Python script and Dropbox to put pictures which taken by my RPi server to my dropbox account. So when RPi takes picture Dropbox sync it to my computer automatically. Also i am using a Pushbullet service call to inform me about taking a picture. (You need to login pushingbox.com and create a scenario for this.)

You need 2 scripts;

1) dropbox_uploader https://github.com/andreafabrizi/Dropbox-Uploader

First, download then run dropbox_uploader to configure it. It will ask for your dropbox credentials and path for pictures.

2) shot-pushinbox-dropbox.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import StringIO
import subprocess
import os
import time
from datetime import datetime
from PIL import Image
import urllib2

# File settings
saveWidth = 1280
saveHeight = 960

# Save a full size image to disk
def saveImage(width, height):
    time = datetime.now()
    filename = "capture-%04d%02d%02d-%02d%02d%02d.jpg" % (time.year, time.month, time.day, time.hour, time.minute, time.second)
    # Take a shot
    subprocess.call("raspistill -w 1296 -h 972 -t 100 -e jpg -q 15 -o %s" % filename, shell=True)
    # Inform PushingBox that we have take a shot
    # Put your "devid" or comment it to disable pushingbox call.
    response = urllib2.urlopen('http://api.pushingbox.com/pushingbox?devid=vXXXXXXXXXXXXX&image_name=%s' % filename)
    # Upload motion image to dropbox
    subprocess.call("bash /usr/local/bin/dropbox.sh upload %s /" % filename, shell=True)

saveImage(saveWidth, saveHeight)
```

Edit as your need.

Answer (score 2):

Another method you could use, is to install a ftp server on your PC and have the PI upload to the server periodically. If you are running an ssh server on the pi then there is always sshfs (ssh file system), sftp which is ftp over ssh (not the same as ftps) and scp (secure copy). The possibilities are endless. Any of these methods can be scripted for autonomy. It's funny I've been researching the same thing today for a PI bird box camera.